# Metro builder does not watch for index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm building a react-native app. I've created Home component and place it to Home folder with index.js and exported it default.

```
export default Home // Home.js
export {default} from './Home' // index.js
// both are in Home folder
```

Then I'm trying to import in other file like this.

```
import Home from '../../screens/Home';
```

But I get error

```
 InternalError Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\SomeLongPath\screens\Home.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed my component like this and it's worked

```
function Home () { // some code }
export default Home;
// to
const Home = () => { // some code };
export default Home'
```